# IllegalAccessException while using java object in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm going to use WebView/WebEngine to display "logs" (i.e. chat message, game status message, ...) for simple multiplayer game.

Here is what I wrote on javascript part.

```js
function addLogMessage(o) {
    var kind = o.getMessageKindCase();
    if (kind.equals(kind.CHAT_MESSAGE)) {
        $("body").append(createChatMessage(o.getChatMessage()));
    } else (/* other cases following... */)
}

function addLogMessages(l) {
    var n = l.size();
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        addLogMessage(l.get(i));
    }
}
```

Here is what I wrote on java part.

```java
private GameStatus gameStatus;
private WebEngine logWebEngine;
private final ObjectProperty<JSObject> window = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "window");

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    gameStatus = /* ... */;

    window.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null) {
            return;
        }
        // getLogMessages() will return java.util.List<LogMessage>
        newValue.call("addLogMessages", gameStatus.getLogMessages());
    });

    logWebEngine = logView.getEngine();
    logWebEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            window.set((JSObject) logWebEngine.executeScript("window"));
        }
    });
    logWebEngine.load(getClass().getResource("log.html").toString());
}
```

When I called addLogMessage() from java side, it works as intended.
However, calling addLogMessages() caused the following exception.

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline can not access a member of class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection with modifiers "public"`

It seems that `l.size()` in addLogMessages caused this exception.

What's the reason of this exception? And, is there any solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe problem with it - Reflection not support anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of zella was helpful for me.

Did not work:

```
DatumFunction<Double> datumFunction = new DatumFunction<Double>(){

        @Override
        public Double apply(int d) {
            String result  = "" + d;
            return value;
        }

};
```

Does work:

```
DatumFunction<Double> datumFunction = new DoubleDatumFunction();
```

with

```
public class DoubleDatumFunction implements DatumFunction<Double> {
        @Override
        public String apply(int d) {
            String result  = "" + d;
            return value;
        }
    }
```

If I would remove the public modifier from the class for the second example, the example would not work any more.